# ASP.NET Core 2.2 - dependency between 2 select form fields

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have 2 select fields.

One showing a list of items:

```
<select id="itemlist" asp-for="WorkTask.ItemId" asp-items="@Model.itemList.ToSelectListItem(Model.WorkTask.ItemId)"></select>
```

One showing a list of customers:

```
<select id="customerlist" asp-for="WorkTask.CustId" asp-items="@Model.customerList.ToSelectListItem(Model.WorkTask.CustId)"></select>
```

I'm using an extension method to fill in the select fields, which looks like this:

```
        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItem<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int selectedValue)
        {
            return from item in items
                   select new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Text = item.GetPropertyValue("Name"),
                       Value = item.GetPropertyValue("Id"),
                       Selected = item.GetPropertyValue("Id").Equals(selectedValue.ToString())
                   };
        }
```

When I choose an item in the first select field, I need to lookup a list of customers (basicly it's only one) the chosen item belongs to, and show that in the last select field.

In the bottom of the MVC view I have the following code:

```
    <script>
        function updateCustomerList() {
            var itemSelected = document.getElementById("itemlist").value;

            $list = $('#customerlist');

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/WorkTask/GetCustomer/' + itemselected,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function (data) {
                    results = JSON.parse(data);

                    $list.html('');
                    for (i in results) {
                        $list.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + results[i].text + '</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            updateCustomerList();
        });

        $('#itemlist').on("change", function () {
            updateCustomerList();
        });

    </script>
```

In the controller (WorkTask) I have the following action:

```
        [ActionName("GetCustomer")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomer(int id)
        {
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

            var item = await _db.Item.FindAsync(id);
            var customer = await _db.Customer.Where(q => q.NavNumber == item.NavNumber).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (customer == null)
            {
                customers = await (from Customer in _db.Customer
                                   select Customer).ToListAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                customers = await (from Customer in _db.Customer
                                   where Customer.Id == Customer.Id
                                   select Customer).ToListAsync();
            }

            return Json(new SelectList(customers, "Id", "Name"));
        }
```

When I run the project and choose an option in the itemlist nothing happens.
I'm getting no errors, and I have no idea about how to proceed.
I have tried to print out values with alert, but I can get no values from the Ajax call.

Both select fields are just filled with items and customers, so this works. It's just the dependency that doesn't work.

When this work, I'll try to make it work the other way around too - When I choose a customer in the last select field, it should show me only items belonging to the chosen customer.

I'm a novice in Ajax code, so maybe one of you Ajax-sharks know how to proceed?

Comment: Did that action work without ajax? as I think the route for this action is not '/Admin/WorkTask/GetCustomer/[id]' but '/Admin/WorkTask/GetCustomer?id=[id]'

Comment: Meruzhan: Yes, I believe you are right. Just tried that out, but still no result. When I choose a value in "itemlist" nothing happens. I'm not sure how I can debug Ajax in Visual Studio. Would definitely be valuable to get some kind of error message from Chrome.

Comment: You can use network panel in Inspections to see what XHR requests are going, and see if the requests provides right results. Also you can debug it by setting breakpoint to your success action from Google Chrome's website sources (also in Inspection)